# How to provide Authentication for external browser in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().getExternalBrowser()
                .openURL(resourceURL);
```

This is to open external browser from an Eclipse plugin with the URL passed but I need to provide basic authentication for this URL.

Using the Browser class I can provide authentication by using `addAuthenticationListener()` to the browser passed but I am unable to figure out how to provide authentication for an external browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external browser is opened in a new process using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(....)` so you are not going to be able to add anything to do authentication in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your response...                                                                      Is it possible to pass  authentication headers while opening the URL in the external browser?

Comment: No, the only thing that is given to the new process is the URL.

Comment: Thank you !  it was helpful